# iMacro: Use a specifc macro if HTML Element present (ATTR=CLASS:img)

Tags: javascript, html, macros

I'm praying someone can help me here.

What I'm trying to accomplish is: if HTML element "X" is present, use A macro. If HTML element "Y" is present, use B macro.

Specific 2 Elements I'm looking for

- TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1thanksgiving&&TXT:
- TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1christmas&&TXT:

I am planning to use javascript to create macro to accomplish. The only part I don't under

Comment: Here is an example of imacros javascript script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336597/javascript-and-imacros-loop

Comment: Thank you macroscripts. However, I am still very inexperienced with javascript... is it possible for you to hold my hands on this one?
  
  
How can I create imacro with Javascript to show that:
If TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1thanksgiving&&TXT: is present, then run Macro1.iim
  
  
If TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1christmas&&TXT: is present, then run Macro2.iim

Answer (score 0):

```
var macro1;

macro1 ="CODE:";
macro1 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1thanksgiving&&TXT:"+"\n";

var macro2;

macro2 ="CODE:";
macro2 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:img_holiday_1christmas&&TXT:"+"\n";


if(iimPlay(macro1)>0)
{
iimPlay("Macro1.iim")

}

if(iimPlay(macro2)>0)
{
iimPlay("Macro2.iim")

}
```